# "Unable to parse the expression. Please make sure it is valid." when typing Dataflow Expression Builder

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm working with Azure Synapse Analytics and I'm facing an issue with the Data Flow expression builder. My goal is to format a column named "Start Date (BST)" which currently has the format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSS to dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss, effectively removing the milliseconds.

[image]

Here's what the date looks like right now:

2022-07-07T23:43:13.722007

I tried using the following expression in the data flow expression builder:

```
toTimestamp('Start Date (BST)', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SS')
```

However, I am getting an error stating "Unable to parse the expression. Please make sure it is valid."

Could someone please guide me on the correct syntax or the steps I should take to format the datetime values properly using the expression builder in Azure Synapse? I would appreciate any insights or examples of the correct expression to achieve this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You expression as below.

```
toString(toTimestamp({Start Date (BST)},'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss'),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

You need to give column name aroung curly braces and need to add **T** like `'T'`
but this will take it as quote so escape it with slash `\` like this `\'T\'`, then format it with using to string.

`Output:`

[image]

But this gives you as a string if you want in timestamp remove `toString` function

and you get output as below.

[image]